# meta regression and bubble plot with metafor package in R

Tags: r, plot

I am working on a meta-regression on the association of year and medication prevalence with 'metafor' package.

The model I used is 'rma.glmm' for mixed-effect model with logit transformed from 'metafor' package.

My R script is below:

```
dat<-escalc(xi=A, ni=Sample, measure="PLO")
print(dat)
model_A<-rma.glmm(xi=A, ni=Sample, measure="PLO", mods=~year)
print(model_A)
```

I did get significant results so I performed a bubble plot with this model. But I found there is no way to perform bubble plot straight away from 'ram.glmm' formula. I did something alternatively:

```
wi<-1/dat$vi
plot(year, transf.ilogit(dat$yi), cex=wi)
```

Apparently I got some 'crazy' results, my questions are:

1> How could I weight points in bubble plot by study sample size? the points in bubble plot should be proportionate to study weight. Here, I used 'wi<-dat$vi'. vi stands for sampling variance, which I got from 'escalc()'. But it doesn't seem right.

2> Is my model correct to investigate the association between year and medication prevalence? I tried 'rma' model I got totally different results.

3> Is there any alternative way to perform bubble plot? I also tried:

```
percentage<-A/Sample
plot(year, percentage)
```

The database is below:

```
study       year    Sample    A
study 1     2007    414      364
study 2     2010    142       99
study 3     1999    15         0
study 4     2000    17         0
study 5     2001    20         0
study 6     2002    22         5
study 7     2003    21         6
study 8     2004    24         7
study 9     1999    203        82
study 10    2009    647       436
study 11    2009    200       169
study 12    2010    156       128
study 13    2009    10753    6374
study 14    2007    143       109
study 15    2001    247        36
study 16    2004    318       184
study 17    2012    611       565
study 18    2013    180       167
study 19    2006    344       337
study 20    2007    209       103
study 21    2013    470       354
study 22    2010    180       146
study 23    2005    522       302
study 24    2000    62         30
study 25    2001    79         39
study 26    2002    85         43
study 27    2011    548       307
study 28    2009    218       216
study 29    2006    2901     2332
study 30    2008    464       259
study 31    2010    650       393
study 32    2008    2514      704
```

Comment: Similar question asked on CrossValidated and answered there (http://stats.stackexchange.com/q/194597/1934).